# stunnel3 : [!] Inetd mode: TLS server needs a certificate [!] Configuration failed

Tags: ssl, stunnel

I'm trying to configure and start stunnel3 but each time I get

```
[!] Inetd mode: TLS server needs a certificate
[!] Configuration failed
```

stunnel.conf

```
cert = /pathto/server.pem
key = /pathto/server.key
client = no
fips = no
sslVersion = all
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1

[stunnel]
accept = 82
connect = 81
```

what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this command

stunnel /pathtowhereisconfigfile/stunnel.conf

then it worked

I also needed to separate the .pem (generated by the stunnel install) into a .crt and .key and in config file

```
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.crt
key = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.key
```